# What is the Klingon Onomotopoeia for laughing?

Tags: star-trek, languages, klingon, klingon-language

Most Onomotopoeia (words that indicate a sound by being similar in structure to the sound like "haha" or "meow") for laughing in human languages are some variation on "haha" or "hehe" or something similar perhaps transliterated with a j or a k.

I've done a fair bit of googling but I've found no answer as to what the Klingon version of this is if there even is one. While Worf might have us believe that Klingons do not laugh, his own examples and others, provide mountains of evidence to the contrary. If there is not an official construction, what would a likely construction be?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For what it's worth, the Klingon word for "to laugh" is **Hagh**. That's onomotopoeic enough, I would think.

Comment: @anaranjada "hagh" might be pronounced "ha".

Comment: @anaranjada That would be the crux to the argument.

Comment: You can listen to the pronunciation of **Hagh** [here](http://hol.kag.org/words/Hagh).

Answer (score 1):

Alexander Rozhenko is a Klingon. In the script for [TNG: Cost of Living](http://www.st-minutiae.com/academy/literature329/220.txt), he laughs repeatedly:

> **ALEXANDER:** ***Ha!*** It's my laughing hour. **Ha! Ha!**

Comment: I'm not sure this is a useful answer.  That's just how they chose to write it in the script.  IOW, it's the out-of-universe *English* onomatopoeia for laughing.

Comment: @Kevin - He's a klingon, he's laughing, it's described *how* he's laughing in an official script treatment. I'm not sure how much more useful it could possibly get :-)

Comment: I can't speak for the OP, but I was wondering how other klingons would describe his laughing, not humans writing a TV script.

Comment: @Kevin - So what would you accept as a reliable source?

Comment: @CodeMed - His mother was half-Klingon. Worf is pure-blood klingon. At best, Alexander is 1/4 Human, 3/4 Klingon.

Comment: @Richard: I imagine it would not be canon as defined by Memory Alpha (i.e. the live-action shows and movies).  It's difficult to get that sort of thing on screen.  But it's at least theoretically possible that one of the novels has discussed this at some point.

Comment: I fail to see what canon you would consider acceptable. Could you amend your question to show what would be suitable?

Comment: Despite Alexander's lineage - his first language is English since he was educated within the Federation, and so would likely be using "HA" like other English speaking people - this wouldn't support its use in Klingon.

Comment: I didn't ask the question and I don't presume to put words in the OP's mouth.

Comment: Potentially *the* most annoying scene in all of TNG

Comment: @N_Soong - The funeral of Ira Graves?

Comment: @Richard; that probably comes second ;)

Comment: I'd be surprised if "OK" doesn't spread to every language in the Federation. Maybe even the Borg would assimilate it.